# variable not available inside of ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

Can anyone explain why my @model variable is not available inside of my ajax call?
When I try to use the @model variable inside of my error callback it does not exist.

```
$.ajax URL+ "/api/v1/menu_items/#{@model.id}/verify",
    type: 'PUT'
    data: formData 

    error: (response) ->
      alert(response)
      window.location.href = "/menu_items/#{@model.id}"
    success: (data) ->
      window.location.href = "/menu_items/#{data.id}"
```

Comment: Read about [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and find out what is uses as `this` in the callbacks. Then maybe use `(response) =>` to use bound functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`=>` fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) when you want to preserve `this` in the outer scope of a function definition.

Check the comments below.

```
$.ajax URL+ "/api/v1/menu_items/#{@model.id}/verify",
    type: 'PUT'
    data: formData 

    # this reference to the `this' where $.ajax is called.

    error: (response) => # a function definition here. use => to bind this to the outer scope
      alert(response)
      window.location.href = "/menu_items/#{@model.id}"
    success: (data) ->
      # in this function, this will be bound to the object on which the success callback is called, normally, null
      window.location.href = "/menu_items/#{data.id}"
```